# Redirect Get-Parameter with .htaccess

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I will redirect this url, with help from .htaccess:

```
http://www.example.com/index.php?q=where is new york?&start=0&type=web
```

to:

```
http://www.example.com/search/where is new york?/0/web
```

knows anybody how i can implement this plan ?
importend is, that the question mark don't reset the other GET-Value.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have it this way in your root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+index\.php\?q=([^\s&]+)&start=([^\s&]+)&type=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /search/%1/%2/%3? [R=302,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(search/[^/]+)/?$ /$1\%3F/%{QUERY_STRING}? [L,NC,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^search/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ search.php?q=$1&start=$2&type=$3 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Comment: You're welcome, glad it worked out. It was a tricky rewrite actually.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} q=(.*)&start=(.*)&type=(.*)
RewriteRule /index\.php search/%1?/%2/%3
```

For the querystring you need to use a condition. Further help can be found [here](http://www.askapache.info//2.3/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to rewrite the url:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /index.php?q=$1&start=$2&type=$3 [L]
```